# Align two div side by side using css, div contain dot icon and text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have to differentiate  value 1 and value 2 using dot icon  so I wrote css for that and placed in div but it is overlapping on each other I just want to show two div side by side with icon and text without overlapping

```css
    .dot {
            height: 12px;
            width: 12px;
            background-color: #bbb;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .user-values-color{
            background-color: #1BBC9B;
           float: left;
        }
        .default-values-color{
            background-color: #2D3E50;
            float: left;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="user-values-color dot" ><span style="float:left;">Value 1</span></div>
    
    <div class="default-values-color dot"><span style="float:left;"> value 2</span></div>
```

[image]

Comment: By over lapping you mean text and circle?

Comment: yes it should  appear side by side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take the span out of the div put it side by side in a parent container like below:

```css
.dot {
   height: 12px;
   width: 12px;
   background-color: #bbb;
   border-radius: 50%;
   display: inline-block;
}
.user-values-color{
  background-color: #1BBC9B;
  float: left;
}
.default-values-color{
  background-color: #2D3E50;
  float: left;
}
.container {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="user-values-color dot" ></div>
    <span style="float:left;">Value 1</span>
  </div>
   <div class="container">
     <div class="default-values-color dot"></div> 
     <span style="float:left;"> value 2</span>
   </div>
```

Comment: but   I am getting one by one (in next line) instead of side by side

Comment: text and circle are in new lines? or 2 circle are in new lines?

Comment: 1st text and circle in one line,  2nd text and circle appeared in new line

Comment: then add .container { display: inline-block; } in your css. I'll update the answer as well

Answer (score 1):

If you are really using bootstrap then you shall learn about [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/), it 's the basic.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-start">
    <div class="col-2">
    Value 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
    value 2
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

now you are just using inline css